# PHP echo return confirm function slashes

Tags: php, javascript

Hi i have been using this php echo statement

```
echo "<a href = 'message_delete_script_outbox.php?id=".$row['id']."'"."onclick='return        
confirm(/Are you sure, you want to delete?/)'>Delete</a>";
```

The statement is working i am seeing this message /Are you sure, you want to delete?/ instead of this Are you sure, you want to delete?

Answer (score 6):

Your quote nesting is a little messed up.  Try to follow these rules:

- Outer quote = `"` (This marks the beginning and end of the string)
- Inner quote = `\"` (Escaped as to not flag "beginning/end of string")
- Third-tier quote = `'` (Literal quote)
- Fourth-tier quote = `\'` (Literal quote that will be generated as an escaped outer quote)

Result:

```
echo "<a href=\"message_delete_script_outbox.php?id=".$row['id']."\"onclick=
      \"return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')\">Delete</a>";
```

More info about quote nesting: http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2007/10/nested-nested-quotes.html

Comment: And he isn't using any quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You enclose the message in quotes, and those quotes need to be escaped to avoid confusing the PHP script:

```
echo "<a href = 'message_delete_script_outbox.php?id=".$row['id']."'"."onclick='return        
confirm(\"Are you sure, you want to delete?\")'>Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add double quotes and escape them

```
echo "<a href = 'message_delete_script_outbox.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure, you want to delete?\")'>Delete</a>";
```

I am not sure if you added a new line when you posted here, but you should know you cannot have that script on 2 lines.